# How do I use requirejs in the browser?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a simple [Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/YgOPZguboF6fu2wp?preview).

```
<script data-main="lib/script.js" src="//requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js"> </script>

//lib/script...
requirejs(["lib/test"], function(test) {
    ...
});
```

Basically I am trying to demo using requirejs. When I try to run the demo I get...

> ReferenceError: requirejs is not defined

and

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: requirejs is not defined

Shouldn't just adding the script add it to window?

I also tried using `require` instead of `requirejs` same result

Comment: try it locally, I tried on https://cch7s.codesandbox.io/ and it works but has other issue

Comment: I appreciate the advise but this is for a presentation and I wanted to avoid any local demos.